# Python, how to create file containing only specific lines beginning with certain phrase

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have certain lines of data within a large file that the only lines I need are the ones that begin with "ABC". I wasn't sure if there was a way to pull all these lines and create a new folder to contain only the xyz coordinates within it, as I need to find the standard deviation and think that would be the best way to go about It. (An example line of the overall file that's being worked with: "ABC 3.2650481094164707 5.5229511970397915 4.8978200015718540")

Ideally it would be a file with column format so that the example coordinates are as such: "3.2650481094164707, 5.5229511970397915, 4.8978200015718540" so that there is an x column, a y column and a z column

The following is the format of the code to obtain just the ABC lines, but I'm unsure how to make them into their own file

```
with open("file",'r') as f:
    sums = [0] * 3
    points = 0
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("ABC "):
            points += 1
            for i, x in enumerate(line.split()[1:]):
                sums[i] += float(x)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of what you would want produced from a given input file, maybe one that is only a few liens long.

Comment: Ideally it would be a file with column format so that the coordinates are as such: "3.2650481094164707, 5.5229511970397915, 4.8978200015718540"

Comment: So that there's an x column, a y column and a z column for the coordinates

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include such clarifications.

Comment: It might be easier for others if that example file was displayed in the question as a markdown block, similar to what you have for your python code

Comment: What problem are you having? Put the data you want in a 2-dimensional list, and then use the `csv` module to write it to a comma-separated file.

Comment: Edited it to hopefully provide more clarification! Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

To get lines from the input file which starts with `ABC` and write it to CSV file you can use next example:

```py
import csv

abc_lines = []
with open("your_file.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if not line.startswith("ABC "):
            continue
        abc_lines.append(line.split()[1:])


with open("data.csv", "w") as f_out:
    writer = csv.writer(f_out)

    writer.writerow(["X", "Y", "Z"])
    writer.writerows(abc_lines)
```

Creates `data.csv`:

```
X,Y,Z
3.2650481094164707,5.5229511970397915,4.8978200015718540
4.2650481094164707,6.5229511970397915,7.8978200015718540
```

---

Input file:

```
ABC 3.2650481094164707 5.5229511970397915 4.8978200015718540
XYZ 3.2650481094164707 5.5229511970397915 4.8978200015718540
ABC 4.2650481094164707 6.5229511970397915 7.8978200015718540
```